# settimezone query issue using carbon in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, laravel-6, php-carbon

i want set timezone like user lead entry today then tommorrow count is yesterday 1 lead entry using carbon how to do it like i have today 5 leads entry then user watch tommorrow then it will yesterday 5 entry display so how to set timezone yesterday i try but not find any solution here is my query

```
$yesterdayLeads = $this->getConversionRateData(
      Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->subDays(1),$timezone)
         ->setTimezone('UTC'), Carbon::parse(Carbon::now(),$timezone)
         ->setTimezone('UTC')->startOfDay()->subDays(1)->addDays(1), 
          $clientId,$salesCenterId, $locationIds,$brand);
```

please suggestion solution

Comment: Say if you have 5 leads entry today and you want to display on site in some format like "1 hour ago" for today and "1 day ago" for tomorrow then you can use `diffForHumans` or `since` on Carbon instances - Is that what you aim for?

Comment: @Donkarnash i want to display lead like 1 day ago but in my query is not working i m using carbon format

Comment: Can you post the code where you are trying to display

Comment: @Donkarnash Means I dont understand what to says what display

Comment: The code where you want the output to be in the format "1 day before"

Comment: @Donkarnash ok so leads['todayLeads'] here is my json response

Comment: I don't quite understand, you are not posting any code for me to understand what you are trying to do. Assuming you want to list all leads records from database in a tabular format maybe you can do`$lead->created_at->diffForHumans()` to get the output like "1 day before" where $lead->created_at is yesterday's date

Comment: @Donkarnash i just want to in my query variable $yesterdayLeads in yesterday day not in front side

Comment: You can still use `$lead->created_at->diffForHumans()` anywhere - in Controller or in any other class, assuming $lead is a Eloquent Model instance representing a row in database

Comment: If you just want to get the count of all leads per day then you can query like `Lead::latest()->get()->groupBy('created_at')`